# Converting DOM element to raw HTML string

Tags: javascript, html

Most of the answers on such questions suggest the usage of `innerHTML` and `outerHTML`. But I don't get what I want. For example:

```
var el = document.createElement("DIV");
el.innerHTML = "<span><% blabla %></span>";
// let's say that el is actually initialized with document.getElementById
// and el = <div><span><% blabla %></span></div>
console.log(el.outerHTML);
```

The result of the above code is

```
"<div><span>&lt;% blabla %&gt;</span></div>"
```

So, the problem is in `<` and `>` and the fact that I'm not getting them. Ok, I understand that the behavior of the browser is kinda normal and I could use `.replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>')` to fix the problem. But checkout the following:

```
el.innerHTML = "<span><% for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) { %> bla bla <% } %>";
console.log(el.outerHTML);
```

The result could not be fixed:

```
<div><span>&lt;% for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)="" {="" %=""> bla bla &lt;% } %&gt;</list.length;></span></div>
```

Any ideas to fix this.

Edit:

I found that the problem is in the `<` sign in the for loop. So if I replace it with `for(var i in list)` then outerHTML returns the proper value.

Comment: Nope. It's a client-side library that uses this information. Similar like Angular. To be more specific this one http://krasimir.github.io/absurd/

Comment: Maybe the variant is to replace `<` and `>` with something else.

Comment: Can't you wait until the library is finished processing the information, then read the *resulting* DOM?

Comment: The idea is that I'll have an already added DOM element and pass it's selector to the library. Then the library should read the html and replace the element with the compiled version.

Comment: <% blabla %> is not html neither javascript ... are you using php? or a template library? give us more info so we can help you properly

Comment: I'm developing a javascript library which uses the following template engine http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Javascript-template-engine-in-just-20-line So in order to update the html I need to get the exact code string. Everything is happening into the browser.

Comment: You have switched around the parameters in your `replace`. It should be needle, replacement. Except for that, I can't really see anything wrong with it. http://jsfiddle.net/3akUb/

Comment: The problem is that I have no control on the html. It should be possible to put my library into the page and start working with it and with the current HTML.

Answer (score -1):

This is a dirty trick, and may not help you if you need to do something "funky" with that strings, but will do the job if you don't mind letting the browser do part of your job for you:

You can "display" it in a div, then take it again in js, and you get exactly the html string.

For example:

```
 var string = "&lt; blabla &gt;";
 $('converterDiv').html(string); // jQuery because I'm lazy
 var convertedString = $('converterDiv').html();
```

Again... is a "bad" trick, but may help you.

Comment: It looks like that the browser tries to use the markup and convert it to something different. Every operation after that returns the converted value. Your solution will work if I control the html, but I can't really force every developer to type `&lt;` instead of `<`. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I told you it is a dirty trick :). To achieve what you want you can take a look at jQuery text() function... it does the conversion the other way around, but maybe will give you an idea how to reverse it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely check jQuery's method.